# What does happen if the ratio of an ideal transformer is complex?

Tags: power, transformer, passive-networks

I have seen two solutions, both of then containing a paradox: Firstly, current and voltage ratio are inverse AND conjugate. In this first case, the two-port matrix is not symmetric (non-reciprocal). Secondly, current and voltage ratio are just inverse (no conjugate). In this second case, the power in the primary is not equal to that in the secondary; depending on the phase of the ratio, the transformer can have even gain or losses.
Which is the correct model? How can be explained non reciprocity in the first case or the difference of power in the second one? Does anybody know any published analytical study on this topic?

Comment: References to the source, and schematics, would help. At the moment the question is meaningless because too much context is missing.

Answer (score 1):

In a normal ideal transformer you have:
\$ V_2=m V_1 \$ and \$ I_1=mI_2\$.

where m is the transformer ratio.

In this special ideal transformer you'll have just the same, except that all variables are phasors (shown in bold) and asterisk symbol is the complex conjugate operation:

\${\bf V_2}= {\bf m} {\bf V_1}\$ and \${\bf I_1}={\bf m}^*{\bf I_2} \$

If you apply those equations there will be no change in power between primary and secondary, and the two-ports is reciprocal.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of a transformer is never anything else other than a straight forward normal number but, in a real transformer there are "extra components" that can make you believe there is something odd going on. Equivalent circuit for a regular AC power transformer: -

[image]

Right in the middle is a fairy-tale perfect power converting transformer and surrounding it are all the things that make this fairy tale into reality.

- Xp and Xs - there are leakage inductances on the primary and secondary i.e. turns that do not couple primary and secondary.
- Xm - the magnetization inductance - basically if the secondary were removed the primary would be an inductor with inctance of Xm.
- Then there are copper losses Rp and Rs and core loss (due to core eddy currents) and possibly core saturation.

This is just a basic AC power transformer but for a high frequency ferrite transformers there are other factors such as inter-winding capacitances etc. maybe something like this: -

[image]