# Is an ideal transformer a reciprocal two-port, and if so, how would you define reciprocity?

Tags: power, transformer, passive-networks

Reciprocity is commonly defined, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(electrical_networks)), such that for `Z-parameters`, `Znm == Zmn`, or `Y-parameters`, `Ynm == Ymn`. However, both the `Z-` and `Y-` parameters of an ideal transformer are singular. Yet, surely, an ideal transformer is a reciprocal, passive, and lossless two-port device.

The cascade (`ABCD`) parameters of a reciprocal two part is commonly said to be one such that `Det[.] == A D - B C == 1` [(see LibreTexts.org)](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electronics/Microwave_and_RF_Design_III_-_Networks_(Steer)/02%3A_Chapter_2/2.2%3A_Two-Port_Networks), which is consistent with `ABCD` parameters for an ideal transformer with real-valued turns-ratio `'n'` given by `ABCD` parameter `{ A = n, B = 0 },{ C = 0, D = 1 / n }`. However, losslessness for a complex valued turns-ratio `'c'` requires `{ A = c, B = 0 },{ C = 0, D = 1 / c* }`, for which `Det[.] == A D - B C == c / c* == Sign[c^2]`, where we have used `.*` to mean the complex conjugate of `.` and `Sign[.] == Exp[I Arg[.]]`.

[see Roger C's answer on the post "What does happen if the ratio of an ideal transformer is complex?"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200498/what-does-happen-if-the-ratio-of-an-ideal-transformer-is-complex/200541)

Is there a definition of reciprocity that one can apply to ideal transformers?

Is it consistent with existing definitions of reciprocity for `Z` and `Y` parameters?

Comment: Tip: You can use limited TeX (specifically MathML) here, just use a `\$` on either side of your equation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is (a reciprocal two port device), and we need to modify the reciprocity relations accordingly.

We can augment the two ports of a transformer with lossless passive reciprocal two-ports that enable Z- and or Y- parameters to be defined. For example adding a shunt susceptance y to both ports of an ideal transformer (with complex turns-ratio) creates another passive, lossless two-port; but one that has a non-singular z-parameter matrix. If we accept that the ideal transformer with a complex turns-ratio is a reciprocal device, the augmented two-port is also reciprocal, and we can examine the properties of the resulting Z-matrix to find a suitable definition of reciprocity for a network containing a complex impedance transform. We can do a similar thing by augmenting using series reactances and the y-parameters. We do not need to explicitly augment the network to find a definition in s-parameters, as s-parameters implicitly augment an n-port with reference impedance terminations -- the s-parameters of a complex impedance transform exist. For a two-port network the s-parameters can be derived directly from ABCD parameters using *accepted* transformations from ABCD parameters to s-parameters for *real valued* reference impedances.

As an example, let a transformer have ABCD matrix `ax` given by `ax = {{c,0},{0,1/c*}}`, and let ABCD matrix of shunt admittance `as = {{1,0},{I y,1}}` (where `I === Sqrt[-1]`) be cascaded on the left and the right of `ax`. The resulting cascade has ABCD parameters given by `asxs = as.ax.as = - I / ( 1 = Abs[c]^2 ) { { Abs[c]^2, c }, { c*, 1 } }`. And we see that `z12/z21 == c/c* == Sign[c^2] == Det[asxs] == Det[ax]`.

Therefore a suitable (necessary and sufficient) condition for reciprocity of a Z-parameter matrix is that `Abs[Znm/Zmn] == 1` for all `n`, `m` (row and column indices of the matrix), whereas `Znm == Zmn` is sufficient, it is not necessary.

Similarly, for a Y-parameter matrix we find the condition `Abs[Ynm/Ymn]` == 1 is necessary and sufficient for it to be reciprocal. For the S-Parameter matrix, we have the necessary and sufficient condition `Abs[Snm/Smn] == 1`.

For the case when a denominator is ZERO, the numerator must also be ZERO for the network to be deemed reciprocal, and the corresponding ports are ISOLATED at the frequency.

For cascade ABCD matrix we have the condition is `Abs[Det[.] == 1`, and for the wave cascade (or chain) matrix T, `Abs[Det[.]] == 1` too.

I think this also implies what a consistent definition of the s-parameters should be for complex reference impedances, which is especially important in the case of s-parameters for reference impedances that differ in their phase. I think the "wave variables" `a` and `b` should be defined as `a=1/2 Abs[v + I z]/sqrt( z* )`, `b=1/2 Abs[v - I z]/sqrt( z* )` for complex port reference impedance `z`. An s-parameter between port `m` and `n` is then the ratio `Snm = b(n)/a(m)`

Comment: I think `Abs[Znm/Zmn] == 1` is too lax. We we should rather have `Znm==Zmn || Znm==Zmn*`, i.e. a reciprocal immettance matrix is either symmetric (the accepted definition) or conjugate-symmetric (an additional case we propose).

Comment: And I think the reciprocity condition becomes `if given I2 ==0, V2 == z21 I1, then given I1==0, V1 == z21 I2 || V1 == z21* I2`.

Comment: I don't know (at this point) whether `Abs[Det[.]] == 1` for an `ABCD` or `T` matrix is sufficiently restrictive to exclude gyrators, in general, from being classified as reciprocal. Though, I think it would be, as in either case `Det[.] == s12/s21`, and it has been shown that gyrators can be used to make devices for which `Abs[Snm] != Abs[Smn]`.

Comment: Please use proper math formatting in your question and answer. I explained above that you can use limited TeX formatting here, please do so--this is very difficult to read.

Comment: Hi @Hearth, could you help with that? I'd need to learn a whole new language to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you go back to your Wikipedia link, you will find:

[image]

If you drive a current into one terminal of your ideal transformer and determine the voltage at the other (assuming some turns ratio and inductance), you will find that you will get the same result when you swap the ports around.

If the primary inductance is \$L_p\$ and the secondary inductance is \$L_s\$ with a turns ratio \$n^2 = \frac{L_s}{L_p}\$, I think that if you drive a current \$i\$ into either port you will measure a voltage \$v=j\omega n L_p i\$ at the other.

This confirms reciprocity.

Comment: Your analysis is quite correct for a transformer with finite inductance (albeit with zero leakage inductance, and so otherwise *ideal*). But I should have been clearer about what I meant by an *ideal* transformer : I meant one that is a synthetic network theoretical component that admits no magnetizing current (sqrt(Lp Ln) is infinite, so to speak) so that if a port is open circuit, you cannot drive any current into the other. A similar thing happens for the dual connection: with a short circuit secondary, one cannot induce a voltage at the primary.

Comment: I think that, even with a real valued turns ratio, I think one could not consider such a "synthetic" device to be reciprocal in a commonly accepted "circuit theoretic" definition derived from the [Lorentz reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(electromagnetism)#Lorentz_reciprocity). It would kind of make sense to adopt some other definition for the *ideal* transformer, as it is clearly not realisable and so cannot be represented by the physics Lorentz described.

Comment: The ideal transformer you describe has a simple and symmetric scattering matrix.  I suspect that by using this, and the definition of incident and reflected waves as traveling EM waves, that you could show that it does satisfy Lorentz reciprocity, but I haven't worked through it.